# What's wrong with my C# codes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, global-variables

Why does the 'injured' value different?

```
public int Health = 500;
public int Injured;

    public int AtkDamage()
    {
        Random AtkRnd = new Random();
        return Injured = AtkRnd.Next(0, 100);
    }


    public int RemainHP()
    {
        return Health -= Injured;
    }
```

Why is 'Injured' in 'RemainHP' is different from the 'Injured' in 'AtkDamage', they are in the same class.Thanks very much.(sorry for poor English)

Comment: because (if they are different) `RemainHP()` is being executed before `AtkDamage()`.

Comment: You want `RemainHP == Health - Injured`, right? This way (`Health -= Injured`) you attack the poor creature each time `RemainHP()` is called...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `=` in `RemainHP`. Right now it is equivalent to

```
Health = Health - Injured;
return Health;
```

You want

```
return Health - Injured
```

Comment: So how to change the 'health' value after the first hit?

Comment: Depends how you code look, but you can simply do `Health -= AtkDamage()` when hitting the creature.